# Assembly type name that can run in an executable file without an assembler

Tags: assembly, executable, windows64

I was attempting to learn the code that is processed natively by the processor, or the machine code, because I was strongly unfulfilled with the difficulty it took to construct an *interpreted* programming language. Instead of creating a practical programming language instead of a esolang, I set out to make a compiled language (**EDIT**: As SO has pointed out, I was extremely flawed in doing this)

However, when I started to learn about assembly and machine code, I realized that 
machine code would vary from operating system. Knowing this, I changed my goal to learning machine code to learning machine code for Windows/Intel Core processor (**EDIT**: Which, again, you pointed out was a really dumb idea).

Then, I realized when I was trying to learn how to make a .exe file (I was 
working on it for 2 years, so I just looked up anything related to machine code because I was desperate), I saw a post on WikiHow. It wasn't binary or the Unicode characters corresponding to the binary numbers, it was assembly (**EDIT**: Which, again, was a bad idea)!

This is how I realized (mistakenly) that I could just put assembly language in a .exe file for it to work. Unfortunately, the WikiHow example didn't work, but I still have a feeling that some type of assembly will work.

**THE PROBLEM:** The problem is that I do not know which type of assembly will be able to work in a .exe file (or an executable file) on my computer.

**THE QUESTION**: What type of assembly can be run from an executable file without any compilers/assemblers compiling the assembly code? (Using Windows 64-bit, Intel Core i5-6400T CPU)

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED SO FAR:** Note: If I gave the full list of everything I've tried, you would get tired of reading this. So I will be saying only a portion of what I have tried so far to solve the problem.

- Have tried the Intel documentation.
- Have tried looking up machine code tutorials
- Have tried using 6502 assembly in a Commodore 64 emulator, looking at the machine code it generated and running the machine code it returned in an executable file.
- Have tried looking up assembly tutorial
- Have tried OllyDbg to disassemble file for me so that I could understand assembly mnemonics turned into machine code
- Looked up assembly tutorial
- Looked up machine code tutorial
- Looked up .exe
- Looked up Intel Core documentation

Help would really be appreciated.

Comment: *This is how I realized that I could just put assembly language in a .exe file for it to work.*  No, that is not how anything works.  Assembly language is a text representation of machine code, and can't be run *directly* by a CPU.  If you have asm text inside a .exe and want to run it, you need your .exe to also include an assembler to turn that text into machine code in a file or in memory (e.g. JIT-compile).  Use an assembler (and linker) to create a binary executable like a normal person.

Comment: two years and no luck?  I found the answer in about 2 seconds using google.  What is your real problem here?

Comment: machine code has nothing to do with the operating system.  It is specific to the processor, but you knew that because you read up on the intel documentation and some MOS 6502 documentation.  Assembly language is simply a human readable form of machine code, a way to program the machine at that level and retain your sanity.  Operating systems support one or a few file formats that contain the machine code, sometimes called binaries but they generally contain more than just the machine code and data.

Comment: The file formats are trivial to find using google or wikipedia or both.

Comment: But trying to learn assembly language programming on an operating system can lead to a lot of protection faults.  Find a simulator, avoid x86 maybe as your 10th instruction set but do not use it to learn assembly language.  pdp11, msp430, arm thumb, arm, these are all good first, second, third, etc instruction sets.  x86 is not obvious, if you do have some strong desire (owning the hardware is a horrible reason, and you own many other processors for every one x86 so if that is your reason then dont do x86) start with an 8086 emulator.

Comment: mips is often used, but it has some non-standard weirdisms that would kind of set you off in how you approach most other processors, good as a third or fourth instruction set, should be tons of simulators out there.

Comment: The thing is, I need to make a compiler for my programming language (because I already made an interpreter), so I need some way to convert to machine code, because if I could just put a compiler in the download, I could convert my programming language to python then use py2exe but I'm looking to compile directly to machine code

Comment: @old_timer: I'd recommend against an 8086 emulator.  16-bit x86 with segmentation is harder to learn than 32-bit or 64-bit code with flat memory and segment registers set up by the OS.  Most of what makes x86 so complex is the OS-dev side of things with setting up modes and so on.  Plain user-space under an OS is not bad, i.e. writing functions you can call from C.  If any of your interest in asm is related to performance, being able to run code on real hardware is a huge advantage over emulators.  And you may already be familiar with a toolchain that makes x86 machine code from C...

Comment: @MilkyWay90: That's a totally different question from what you asked.  But ok, in that case I'd recommend generating LLVM-IR in your front-end, and linking with the LLVM libraries to optimize that code and turn it into machine code in object files for whatever target platform: **[Implementing a Language with LLVM](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/index.html)**.  Or use the gcc back-end if you want.  Or even compile to C and feed that C through a compiler; many languages start out that way.  Writing an *optimizing* compiler takes *years* of work for an expert.

Comment: "I was trying to learn machine code because I wanted to make my own compiled programming language" I want to learn about masonry, so I started to build my own cathedral. what about starting with easy stuff?

Comment: if you limit yourself to 8086 code, DOS, and a size of 64k, you CAN write machine-code binary to .COM files. ( Assume the start address to be 0x100 )

Comment: @PeterCordes to overcome the nuances of the x86 family it is far easier to dive in with the 8086.  Segmentation is everywhere it is not an x86 thing, in the sense of having windows of address spaces, to access other memory spaces.  Segmentation is very much present and very much a problem in the x86 solution of today, not in the terms of segment registers but in the overall addressing solution for items in  the addressing space.

Comment: @PeterCordes If you are interested in learning an instruciton set then an operating system is your enemy, months/years down the road if you have an interest in pushing into those areas of the instruction set then you should by then have several instruction sets under your belt as the second and third and nth go by much faster than the first (assuming you choose wisely with the first (and second and maybe third)). so you can get into operating system nuances, etc with one of the ones you know that makes sense (arm or mips for example).

Comment: DOS continues to be the best embedded operating system because of its freedom it is still VERY much in use today.  Comes with debug.exe which is a free assembler and disassembler and builds .com files, you can learn to make system calls, and do a great number of things, dosbox, bochs, etc are easy to come by.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 compilers dont compile to machine code in general.  There are some that are built that way for a reason, but in general it makes no sense.  Python was designed to compile to a generic instruction set that is not something built in hardware, but interpreted at runtime by a virtual machine, just like JAVA but a different instruction set.  C and others compile to assembly then use the already existing assembler and linker (natural progression of a new instruction set).  The big name tools you think of work this way.

Comment: @MilkyWay90 at the same time the big name tools llvm, gcc, etc naturally have an internal code or set of tables as an intermediate step to the backend.  Not necessarily instruction sets.  If you wish to design a new language, that is your goal the intermediate level.  The backend is a separate project, if you go with llvm or gnu you only need to do the frontend, the backend comes for free.  If you wish to learn the backend then dont bother with the frontend/new language for now, these are separate educational projects.

Comment: No matter what it is you are actually wanting to do since we cant really figure it out, you have to divide it into manageable/digestible portions.  Do your system engineering.  And attack each portion separately  (by also dividing that up into digestible portions), part of system engineering is to yes continue to think about the big picture and how the sections fit together, but your success rate and quality will go down if you try to attack the entire project in parallel.

Comment: if this is your first time with a front end, middle, and back end, expect to start over or re-design several times.  You will not hit a home run the first time at bat, if you think you hit a home run the first time through, you didnt, start over, improve.  The opera joke is it aint over till the fat lady sings.  In engineering (software or other) the management joke is its not done until you shoot the engineer, as the engineer will keep tuning and perfecting until forced to stop.  Be that engineer.

Comment: If you want to create your own, entire toolchain...digestible portions...Your goal here seems to be I want to make my own programming language.  Well DO THAT, dont worry about the back end, cross that bridge when you get there (through the several attempts at success), parsing a language and converting what you have parsed into a generic internal set of tables or code that have some chance at being implemented in a backend, is a fair amount of work.  Using existing tools as a model, you can get a feel for how to make yours.  Possibly by starting with theres then going off on your own path.

Comment: Can I use the Commodore 64 for an emulator (is 6502 assembly a good option for starters)?

Comment: @old_timer: If you want to learn osdev / privileged instructions, then an OS is an obstacle.  If you want to start by learning how compilers compile to asm / machine code to produce programs that work under an OS, you just need to know that they take care of setting up memory, and saving/restoring regs on context switches.  That's enough while you learn about how to implement C or pseudo-code in asm, without worrying yet how to set up the machine.  It's not clear why if OP has any interest in embedded systems at all, given talk of making a .exe.  And DEBUG.EXE is a bad assemble, BTW.

Answer (score 3):

> THE PROBLEM: The problem is that I do not know which type of assembly
>   will be able to work in a .exe file (or an executable file) on my
>   computer.
>
> THE QUESTION: What type of assembly can be run from an executable file
>   without any compilers/assemblers compiling the assembly code? (Using
>   Windows 64-bit, Intel Core i5-6400T CPU)

There are exceptions that feel like this happens.  But no assembly language executes directly.  Assembly language is meant to be a human readable/writeable form of machine code.  It is very much more than that to make it more usable, but some percentage of your code is syntax that maps to an instruction, ideally one to one line of asm to a single machine code instruction.

Compilers, C, etc compile to assembly language then the compiler calls the assembler which turns that into an object file, and then depending on how you used the compiler can/will call the linker to turn that into the final executable that the operating system understands.

Operating systems will tend to support a very limited number of binary formats.  The binary formats for the well known operating systems, windows, linux, etc are trivial to google and find the details on, takes  seconds to land on a page with the details.  Even if using the same file format, elf for example, the operating system is its own thing, it has rules as to what the binary must contain and how a binary must run for that operating system.  Take the same hardware, the same exact physical PC, run DOS, Linux, Windows, OSX, and the binary formats and the rules for for what those binaries contain, in particular the system calls into the operating system and what you wrap those with, vary.  The assembler and linker which already exist are aware of the binary format for that operating system and target instruction set.  If you want to make a language then you start with the front end, and then do the middle, the most complicated part of the whole project.  Once you get past the middle, turning the high level language into digestible atomic operations, that can be then ported into one or more instruction sets through the backend.  Operating system calls are handled by libraries usually not necessarily the language, JAVA, Python and some others being exceptions.  So a printf in C links into a C library which has target and operating system specific assembly language to bridge the layer into the operating system, with some percentage (for printf that is HUGE) of code that is ideally in that same language and compiled then or usually at some time in the past into a linkable library.

Honestly it sounds like you are not ready to make a compiler you need to learn some basics, by examining some simple tools that are small enough to be understandable.  Find course material or an online/free class (or book/books) that covers these basic tools topics, assembler and linker, then compiler.  Look at a language like pascal or ada which are somewhat ridid, easier to parse and turn into something vs say C/C++.  Dont look at gnu or llvm or other big projects for educational reasons, they are not the right path.  Once you get into gnu you find it is barely held together with duct tape and bailing wire.  LLVM has some nice documentation which doesnt match the actual tool, maybe many years ago but not anymore.  And as time passes it is also accumulating duct tape and bailing wire as well, it will take a while to catch up to gnu in that respect, but I expect it will eventually, its the nature of these kinds of projects.

Many if not all computer science programs have a compiler class, in order for the students to have any kind of chance at success within a semester the language to compile and the use of existing tools is tuned for this.  Go find some of these classes (google is your friend), and here and there on github or elsewhere you find the occasional student that posts their code.  This is often a case of thinking they hit a home run, but is usually more of I barely got it to work.  But in either case home run or other, one assumes they passed the class with that solution, so it is in theory digestible as it was a semesters worth of work, tens of hours.

short answer:

You cannot execute assembly language, processors execute machine code and the machine code is PROCESSOR specific not operating system.

Binary files, .exe, elf, coff, com, ihex, srec, etc are not specific to the operating system necessarily, but an operating system will have a limited set of, possibly only one, file format they support.

There exists an assembler and linker for your operating system that know the target machine code and know the executable file format.  As with other compiler authors, if your desire here is to invent a new language and make a compiler for it, then compile to assembly language and let those tools do the rest.  This is called a toolchain, a chain of tools (compiler, assembler, linker).  You are working the compiler tool in the chain.

Comment: I highly recommend you do not go after x86 first, based on all the choices out there ARM is going to provide you with a much higher chance of success, use an emulator (qemu, etc) or just get a raspberry pi, I also highly recommend going with the pi-zero, for the same reason I recommend you avoid the x86 you mentioned.  Aim for an arm9 in simulation or an arm11 in sim or hardware.  avoid the cortex-A and modern x86's for now.  Save that for later as that greatly complicates your task.

Comment: the pdp11 is probably the best most orthogonal instruction set, was what was being used to create C and unix, the problem with it is not availability simh runs in a lot of places, but was created by octal thinking folks and we generally think hex now, it does have a gcc backend that is maintained, but binutils syntax does not match the documentation.  the msp430 which is clearly a decendent and or a ripoff, is excellent for a first instruction set, and a first target for a compiler backend, but its baremetal which is fine, but probably not what you were after.

Comment: so arm or thumb makes a lot of sense.  then hit up mips and if you really have to x86, by then your chance of success with x86 will be higher.  If you work your way up to target the llvm bitcode, then you no longer have to care so much about target and can simply focus on your compiler and language, lean on the existing backends to solve the target issues.

Comment: "Many if not all computer science programs have a compiler class" But thats in high school, and I'm trying to learn ahead